# Improving the performance of FOR loop

Tags: performance, excel, vba

I am comparing sheets in a workbook. The workbook has two sheets named PRE and POST with the same 19 columns in each. The number of rows varies every day but are same for the two sheets on a particular day. The macro compares each row in the PRE sheet to the corresponding row in the POST sheet and deletes the rows in both sheets if they are identical.

I have the usually suggested methods of improving performance like screen updating set to FALSE etc.

I want to optimize the two `FOR NEXT` loops.

```
Dim RESULT As String

iPRE = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("PRE").Range("A1", Worksheets("PRE").Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
'MsgBox iPRE
iPOST = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("POST").Range("A1", Worksheets("POST").Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
'MsgBox iPOST

If iPRE <> iPOST Then
    MsgBox "The number of rows in PRE and POST sheets are not the same. The macro quits"
    Exit Sub

Else
    iRows = iPRE
End If

 'Optimize Performance

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    EventState = Application.EnableEvents
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    CalcState = Application.Calculation
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    PageBreakState = ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks
    ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False

    For iCntr = iRows To 2 Step -1
        For y = 1 To 20
            If Worksheets("PRE").Cells(iCntr, y) <> Worksheets("POST").Cells(iCntr, y) Then
                RESULT = "DeleteN"
                Exit For
            Else
                RESULT = "DeleteY"
            End If
        Next y

        If RESULT = "DeleteY" Then
            Worksheets("PRE").Rows(iCntr).Delete
            Worksheets("POST").Rows(iCntr).Delete
        End If
    Next iCntr

    'Revert optmizing lines

    ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = PageBreakState
    Application.Calculation = CalcState
    Application.EnableEvents = EventState
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Deleting Rows (Row by Row) is slow , try to use `Union` and delete all Rows by one time, for example if your macro will delete 1000 rows, using `Union` will be 1000 times faster,but if you want to delete 1 or 2 rows this method will not help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any references to a worksheet cells is slow.  This adds up dramatically when you do it in a loop.  The best speed increase will come from limiting these worksheet references.

One good way is to copy the data in Variant Arrays, and loop over these, building a new Variant Array with the data to be kept.  Then place the new array over the old in one go in one go.

Using a test data set of 200,000 rows, 20 columns, 50% text, 50% numbers, deleting 170,000 rows: this code runs in about 30s on my hardware

```
Sub Mine2()
    Dim T1 As Long, T2 As Long, T3 As Long

    Dim ResDelete As Boolean
    Dim iPRE As Long, iPOST As Long
    Dim EventState  As Boolean, CalcState As XlCalculation, PageBreakState As Boolean
    Dim iCntr As Long, y As Long, iRows As Long
    Dim rPre As Range, rPost As Range

    Dim PreDat As Variant, PostDat As Variant, PreDelDat As Variant, PostDelDat As Variant

    Dim n As Long
    Dim wsPre As Worksheet, wsPost As Worksheet

    Set wsPre = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("PRE")
    With wsPre
        Set rPre = .Range(.Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
        PreDat = rPre.Value
        iPRE = UBound(PreDat, 1)
        'MsgBox iPRE
    End With

    Set wsPost = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("POST")
    With wsPost
        Set rPost = .Range(.Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
        PostDat = rPost.Value
        iPOST = UBound(PostDat, 1)
        'MsgBox iPOST
    End With

    If iPRE <> iPOST Then
        MsgBox "The number of rows in PRE and POST sheets are not the same. The macro quits"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    iRows = iPRE


    ReDim PreDelDat(1 To UBound(PreDat, 1), 1 To UBound(PreDat, 2))
    ReDim PostDelDat(1 To UBound(PostDat, 1), 1 To UBound(PostDat, 2))
    n = 1
    On Error GoTo EH:
 'Optimize Performance

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    EventState = Application.EnableEvents
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    CalcState = Application.Calculation
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    PageBreakState = ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks
    ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False


    T1 = GetTickCount
    For y = 1 To UBound(PreDat, 2)
        PreDelDat(1, y) = PreDat(1, y)
        PostDelDat(1, y) = PostDat(1, y)
    Next

    n = 2
    For iCntr = 2 To UBound(PreDat, 1)
        ResDelete = True
        For y = 1 To UBound(PreDat, 2)
            If PreDat(iCntr, y) <> PostDat(iCntr, y) Then
                ResDelete = False
                Exit For
            End If
        Next y

        If Not ResDelete Then
            For y = 1 To UBound(PreDat, 2)
                PreDelDat(n, y) = PreDat(iCntr, y)
                PostDelDat(n, y) = PostDat(iCntr, y)
            Next
            n = n + 1
        End If
    Next iCntr
    T2 = GetTickCount
    Debug.Print "Compare Done in:", T2 - T1
    Debug.Print "Rows to delete:", n - 1

    rPre = PreDelDat
    rPost = PostDelDat

    T3 = GetTickCount
    Debug.Print "Delete Done In:", T3 - T1
CleanUp:
    'Revert optmizing lines
    On Error Resume Next
    ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = PageBreakState
    Application.Calculation = CalcState
    Application.EnableEvents = EventState
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Exit Sub
EH:
    ' Handle Errors here
    Debug.Assert False
    Resume
    Err.Clear
    Resume CleanUp
End Sub
```

---

Original:

One good way is to copy the data in Variant Arrays, and loop over these, building a reference to cells to delete later.  Then do the delete in one go.

Other general tips:

- Declare *all* variables
- Use more appropriate data types (Long, Boolean)
- Use `End(xlUp)` to avoid failing at unexpected blanks (unless you *want* to stop at the first blank)

Refactored code:

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim ResDelete As Boolean
    Dim iPRE As Long, iPOST As Long
    Dim EventState  As Boolean, CalcState As XlCalculation, PageBreakState As Boolean
    Dim iCntr As Long, y As Long, iRows As Long
    Dim rPreDelete As Range, rPostDelete As Range

    Dim PreDat As Variant, PostDat As Variant

    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("PRE")
        PreDat = .Range(.Cells(1, 20), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).Value
        iPRE = UBound(PreDat, 1)
        'MsgBox iPRE
    End With

    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("POST")
        PostDat = .Range(.Cells(1, 20), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).Value
        iPOST = UBound(PostDat, 1)
        'MsgBox iPOST
    End With

    If iPRE <> iPOST Then
        MsgBox "The number of rows in PRE and POST sheets are not the same. The macro quits"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    iRows = iPRE

    On Error GoTo EH:
 'Optimize Performance

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    EventState = Application.EnableEvents
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    CalcState = Application.Calculation
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    PageBreakState = ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks
    ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False

    For iCntr = 2 To UBound(PreDat, 1)
        ResDelete = True
        For y = 1 To 20
            If PreDat(iCntr, y) <> PostDat(iCntr, y) Then
                ResDelete = False
                Exit For
            End If
        Next y

        If ResDelete Then
            If rPreDelete Is Nothing Then
                Set rPreDelete = Worksheets("PRE").Rows(iCntr)
                Set rPostDelete = Worksheets("POST").Rows(iCntr)
            Else
                Set rPreDelete = Application.Union(rPreDelete, Worksheets("PRE").Rows(iCntr))
                Set rPostDelete = Application.Union(rPostDelete, Worksheets("POST").Rows(iCntr))
            End If
        End If
    Next iCntr
    If Not rPreDelete Is Nothing Then
        rPreDelete.Delete
        rPostDelete.Delete
    End If

CleanUp:
    'Revert optmizing lines
    On Error Resume Next
    ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = PageBreakState
    Application.Calculation = CalcState
    Application.EnableEvents = EventState
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Exit Sub
EH:
    ' Handle Errors here

    Resume CleanUp
End Sub
```

Comment: Many thanks Chris for your kind help. I did try the code but initially it threw up the runtime error 7 due to some memory issues. it showed the error while executing the following line   PostDat = .Range(.Cells(1, 20), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).Value.   I restarted my machine and tried again, but this time Excel hung and could not recover even after being left overnight. Do you have any idea why? One reason of course could be my data has 2.1m rows. Anything else can be done? I will also try the code given by SilentRevolution but as you said its functionally similar to your code

Comment: @TamalBose I have tested the code without issue.  (250,000 rows of random data)

Comment: I may also add here that my original code which is of course not efficient, was able to finish the job in about 4 hours

Comment: How much faster this code will be than yours will depend on your data set.  I achieved similar improvements as posted by SilentRevolution:8.5 sec vs 24.7s for 250,000 rows, 500ish deleted.  Can you describe your data? (total initial rows?, rows deleted?, are there formulas in the data?)

Comment: @ Chris Nielsen, my data is like 200,000 rows in each sheet,  20 columns, rows deleted will vary depending on the Change in the application between Pre and Post but a ball park number of 170,000  can be assumed. There are no formulas in the data. My original code runs in about 4 hours, so bringing it down to half of that would be quite an achievement

Comment: one more, my data does not only have numbers, there are strings/characters as well. One example row is               TRANSACTIONINTERNAL ENTITY PORTFOLIO ACCOUNTINGSECTION TRANSACTIONFAMILY TRANSACTIONGROUP TRANSACTIONTYPE INSTRUMENT TRANSACTIONEXPIRY STATUS VALIDATIONSTATUS NOMINALAMOUNT PL_CURRENCY MVLEGCURRENT MVCURRENCY FIXEDVARIABLELEG DISCOUNTEDMARKETVALUE DISCOUNTEDFUTURECASH FINANCEDPASTCASH SALESMARGIN REPORTDATE
100000 SYDMEL_CE IRO_SYDMEL TradHedge IRD IRS  USD LIBOR S 3M 29/09/1931 MKT_OP Matched 12500000 USD 1 USD V -5036079.6 0 0 0 11/12/2015. You can try to paste above in Excel

Comment: Thanks @ChrisNielsen. I will test the code tomorrow and revert. Thanks once again

Comment: @ChrisNielsen - it worked like magic :). At first i got a run time error so i restarted my machine. Then it was done in a flash, don't think it took more than 20 seconds. many thanks for helping me out

Answer (score 2):

If I may put my two cents in, here is my suggestion.

I've tested the original code (with the the only alteration being the `For y = 1 to 10` instead of `For y = 1 to 20`) and my code against 2 sheets with 10 columns and (initially 500,000) 250,000 rows data each. The reason I've used 10 instead of 20 lies in the fact that I don't know what data is in the columns and as a substitute I have used a random value of either 1 or 2.

- For 10 columns that means that there are `2^10 = 1,024` possibilities.
- For 20 columns that means that there are `2^20 = 1,048,576` possibilities.

As I wanted to have at least the possibility of a few equal rows in each table I opted for the 10 column scenario.

To time the macro I set up a timer macro which calls the macro to compare and delete data.

In order to be able to compare the results both macros were executed directly after starting Excel and opening the file with the exact same data.

I have

- avoided all instances of `Active`
- minimized the reading and writing of data between Excel and VBA which is accomplished by collecting all data on a sheet in a 2D array and then analyzing the array.
- collected the rows to delete in ranges (1 per sheet) and deleted all the rows to be deleted outside the loop

### The Code

```
Sub CompareAndDelete()
    Dim WsPre As Worksheet, WsPost As Worksheet
    Dim Row As Long, Column As Long
    Dim ArrPre() As Variant, ArrPost() As Variant
    Dim DeleteRow As Boolean
    Dim DeletePre As Range, DeletePost As Range

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    With ThisWorkbook
        Set WsPre = .Worksheets("PRE")
        Set WsPost = .Worksheets("Post")
    End With

    ArrPre = WsPre.Range(WsPre.Cells(1, 1), WsPre.Cells(WsPre.Cells(WsPre.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row, 20))
    ArrPost = WsPost.Range(WsPost.Cells(1, 1), WsPost.Cells(WsPost.Cells(WsPost.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row, 20))

    If Not UBound(ArrPre, 1) = UBound(ArrPost, 1) Then
        MsgBox "Unequal number of rows in sheets PRE and POST. Exiting macro.", vbCritical, "Unequal sheets"
    Else

        For Row = 2 To UBound(ArrPre, 1)
            DeleteRow = True
            For Column = 1 To UBound(ArrPre, 2)
                If Not ArrPre(Row, Column) = ArrPost(Row, Column) Then
                    DeleteRow = False
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next Column

            If DeleteRow = True Then
                If DeletePre Is Nothing Then
                    Set DeletePre = WsPre.Rows(Row)
                    Set DeletePost = WsPost.Rows(Row)
                Else
                    Set DeletePre = Union(DeletePre, WsPre.Rows(Row))
                    Set DeletePost = Union(DeletePost, WsPost.Rows(Row))
                End If

            End If
        Next Row

        If Not DeletePre Is Nothing Then DeletePre.Delete
        If Not DeletePost Is Nothing Then DeletePost.Delete

    End If

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With

End Sub
```

### Results

> #### My Code - 500,000 rows of data.
>
> Datasheet with 500.000 rows and 10 columns has been processed in 14,23 seconds, 561 rows have been found equal and have been deleted.
>
> #### Original Code - 500,000 rows of data.
>
> Unfortunately my system couldn't handle this task and Excel stopped working.
>
> ---
>
> #### My Code - 250,000 rows of data.
>
> Datasheet with 250.000 rows and 10 columns has been processed in 4,72 seconds, 313 rows have been found equal and have been deleted.
>
> #### Original Code - 250,000 rows of data.
>
> Datasheet with 250.000 rows and 10 columns has been processed in 14,07 seconds, 313 rows have been found equal and have been deleted.

Comment: This is functionaly identical code to mine.  Thx for testing it.

Comment: It seems you are right @chrisneilsen. Hadn't noticed that though. I was working on it for a while and initially had a different setup but that was more inefficient than the original code so I scrapped that but still wanted to find a solution and when that was done and tested you had already posted it yours. I still wanted to show the result though.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps you can go with 2 adjustments, although their performance impact will be only very small:

```vb
' prepare references to worksheets
Dim WorksheetPRE As Worksheet
Dim WorksheetPOST As Worksheet
Set WorksheetPRE = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("PRE")
Set WorksheetPOST = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("POST")
```

and then, in your code, replace `ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("PRE")` for `WorksheetPRE` etc.

I think no other significant optimizations are possible *when you stay in Excel*. Remember, Microsoft Excel is primarily a [spreadsheet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spreadsheet) calculator, not a data-table processing tool.

If I really needed to speed-up the comparisons, then I would go with one of these approaches:

- link Excel worksheet to Microsoft Access as table and perform the comparison in Access (easiest)
- as the above, but instead of linking the table, *import* it
- as the above two, but use Microsoft SQL Server (Express version is free)