# Using UNION and Ranges To Speed Up Deleting Columns?

Tags: vba, excel

**Trying to use `Union` and ranges to speed up deleting empty columns**, across all sheets in my workbook, except "AA" and "Word Frequency"

Sample [workbook](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByUcHTNcynugb1F5SktqVGQzWGs/view?usp=sharing)

Example of sheet before:
[image]

Example of sheet after (note, I will need to write separate script to shift keywords up, you can't see all the keywords, but only the columns with data in them are left):

[image]

In my search for a method to speed up deleting columns in a sheet if the column is empty **(except the header)**, I was directed by @chrisneilsen to reference the thread [Improving the performance of FOR loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34563525/improving-the-performance-of-for-loop).

That thread shed light on the fact that deleting columns individually slows down performance significantly. Script speed can be improved  by defining a "master" range to include all the ranges (columns) to be deleted (by using `Union`), and then simply deleting the "master" range.

---

As a VBA noob, I used to following references to learn about Ranges, `Union`, `UBound` and `LBound` to understand the code in the thread mentioned above:

Excel-Easy.com: [Using UBound and LBound](http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/size-of-an-array.html)**,**  [Dynamic Arrays (Using ReDim)](http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/dynamic-array.html)
Youtube: [Using UNION method to select (and modify) multiple ranges](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ou11CTTVDJY&feature=youtu.be&t=8m20s)

---

**My old (slow) script** that works, but takes about about 3 hours to run across ~30 sheets and deleting ~100 columns each sheet:

```
Sub Delete_No_Data_Columns()

    Dim col As Long
    Dim h 'to store the last columns/header

    h = Range("E1").End(xlToRight).Column 'find the last column with the data/header

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For col = h To 5 Step -1
        If Application.CountA(Columns(col)) = 1 Then Columns(col).Delete
    Next col

End Sub
```

---

**Almost working script** (for one sheet), using the same approach as @chrisneilsen code in [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34563525/improving-the-performance-of-for-loop) mentioned above. When I run it, it doesn't do anything, however @chrisneilsen noted there were 2 syntax errors (Column. instead of Columns.) and that I was mixing an implicit `ActiveSheet` (by using Columns without a qualifier) with an explicit sheet `Worksheets("Ball Shaker")`. Errors in code are commented below.

```
Sub Delete_No_Data_Columns_Optimized()

    Dim col As Long
    Dim h 'to store the last columns/header
    Dim EventState As Boolean, CalcState As XlCalculation, PageBreakState As Boolean
    Dim columnsToDelete As Range
    Dim ws as Worksheet '<<<<<<<<< Fixing Error (qualifying "Columns." properly)

    On Error GoTo EH:
    'Optimize Performance

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    EventState = Application.EnableEvents
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    CalcState = Application.Calculation
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    PageBreakState = ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks
    ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False

' <<<<<<<<<<<<< MAIN CODE >>>>>>>>>>>>>>

    Set ws = ActiveSheet

    h = Range("E1").End(xlToRight).Column 'find the last column with the data/header

    '<<<<<<<<<<<<<< Errors corrected below in comments >>>>>>>>>>>>           
    For col = h To 5 Step -1
        If Application.CountA(Column(col)) = 1 Then  
        '<<<<< should be Application.CountA(ws.Columns(col)) = 1
            If columnsToDelete Is Nothing Then

            Set columnsToDelete = Worksheets("Ball Shaker").Column(col)
                'should be columnsToDelete = ws.Columns(col)
            Else
                Set columnsToDelete = Application.Union(columnsToDelete, Worksheets("Ball Shaker").Column(col))
                'should be columnsToDelete = Application.Union(columnsToDelete, ws.Columns(col))
            End If
        End If
    Next col
    '<<<<<<<<<<<<<< End Errors >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>

    If Not columnsToDelete Is Nothing Then
        columnsToDelete.Delete
    End If

' <<<<<<<<<<<< END MAIN CODE >>>>>>>>>>>>>>

CleanUp:
    'Revert optmizing lines
    On Error Resume Next
    ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = PageBreakState
    Application.Calculation = CalcState
    Application.EnableEvents = EventState
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Exit Sub
EH:
    ' Handle Errors here

    Resume CleanUp
End Sub
```

---

**Working code that runs across all sheets in workbook**, in about ~6 minutes (except "AA" and "Word Frequency" worksheets, which I don't need to format):

```
Option Explicit

Sub Delete_No_Data_Columns_Optimized_AllSheets()

Dim sht As Worksheet

For Each sht In Worksheets

    If sht.Name <> "AA" And sht.Name <> "Word Frequency" Then
        sht.Activate    'go to that Sheet!
        Delete_No_Data_Columns_Optimized sht.Index  'run the code, and pass the sht.Index _
                                                    'of the current sheet to select that sheet
    End If
Next sht    'next sheet please!


End Sub

Sub Delete_No_Data_Columns_Optimized(shtIndex As Integer)

    Dim col As Long
    Dim h 'to store the last columns/header
    Dim EventState As Boolean, CalcState As XlCalculation, PageBreakState As Boolean
    Dim columnsToDelete As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = Sheets(shtIndex)   'Set the exact sheet, not just the one that is active _
                                'and then you will go through all the sheets

    On Error GoTo EH:
    'Optimize Performance

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    EventState = Application.EnableEvents
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    CalcState = Application.Calculation
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    PageBreakState = ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks
    ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False

' <<<<<<<<<<<<< MAIN CODE >>>>>>>>>>>>>>

    h = ws.Range("E1").End(xlToRight).Column 'find the last column with the data/header


    For col = h To 5 Step -1
        If ws.Application.CountA(Columns(col)) = 1 Then  'Columns(col).Delete
            If columnsToDelete Is Nothing Then
                Set columnsToDelete = ws.Columns(col)
            Else
                Set columnsToDelete = Application.Union(columnsToDelete, ws.Columns(col))
            End If
        End If
    Next col

    If Not columnsToDelete Is Nothing Then
        columnsToDelete.Delete
    End If

' <<<<<<<<<<<< END MAIN CODE >>>>>>>>>>>>>>

CleanUp:
    'Revert optmizing lines
    On Error Resume Next
    ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = PageBreakState
    Application.Calculation = CalcState
    Application.EnableEvents = EventState
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Exit Sub
EH:
    ' Handle Errors here

    Resume CleanUp
End Sub
```

**Note:** Trying to delete columns and shift to left, so columns with data inside will all be grouped together neatly after script is run.

Is this the best way to utilize Union and ranges for deleting columns? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In your second grouping of code you're attempting to use .notation on a variable of type long, which is not proper.  You can use this type of notation on set objects that you can manipulate attributes of with this notation.  You used an example of this in your top block of code with "Application.ScreenUpdating = False."  You could also use such notation for other things like Worksheets, workbooks, etc.  "Workbooks(getBook).Activate" etc.  You have to be careful when accessing Application attributes because they are program wide.  You must ALWAYS reinitialize ScreenUpdating back to True

Comment: @StormsEdge - It is not necessary to make `ScreenUpdating = True`. It flips back after the program completes.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman hmm I had an issue with that earlier where my screen was not updating and I had fixed it by reinitializing back to true in the immediate window.  Perhaps that was not the culprit.  Thank you for the heads up!

Comment: @chrisneilsen - I edited the question to make it more about using Union and Ranges in my particular situation, maybe it will help others not familiar with Union to speed up deleting their columns. Can you provide any input on my updated code that doesn't work?

Comment: @sikorloa _not worling_ is not a sufficient problem explanation.

Comment: @chrisneilsen - Where do you recommend getting help for this problem / what I should change the question to

Comment: @sikorloa show us some sample data, explain what you want to achieve, and what your code actually does and why it is wrong

Comment: @sikorloa having looked closer at your code you have two issues: you are mixing an implicit `ActiveSheet` (by using `Columns` without a qualifier) with an explicit sheet (`Worksheets("Ball Shaker")`) and a spelling mistake (`Worksheets("Ball Shaker").Column(col)` instead of `Worksheets("Ball Shaker").Columns(col)` with an `s`)

Comment: @chrisneilsen - Thanks Chris, you were right. I edited the code and actually got it to work, I'll add it in my question. Goes across all sheets in 6 minutes instead of ~3 hours like before. Do you want to create an answer so I can mark it as the solution? Also - do you know of any downfalls / things to look out for when using the "Union" method for deleting columns?

Comment: @sikorloa now that you have sorted those issues, the Q _is_ a duplicate, so I'll leave it closed as such

Comment: @chrisneilsen - I used your suggestions to create a new code that runs across all sheets, it seems to work, hope I'm not missing anything that might cause errors down the line. Thanks again for the suggestions to get it to work, I appreciate it. Updated code in last section of question.

Answer (score 2):

The special cells method actually will not serve you so well here. Instead, find the last row of data in your sheet and delete only the cells in the column up to the that row and shift everything to the left. This will be *much* faster than deleting an entire column!

```
Sub Delete_No_Data_Columns()

    Dim col As Long, lRow as Long
    Dim h as Long'to store the last columns/header

   lRow = Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row ' assumes column E will have last used row ... adjust as needed

    h = Range("E1").End(xlToRight).Column 'find the last column with the data/header

    For col = h To 5 Step -1
        If Application.CountA(Columns(col)) = 1 Then 
          Range(Cells(2,col),Cells(lRow,col)).Delete shift:=xlToLeft
        End If
    Next col
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False ' i think you want this at the beginning of the program, no?

End Sub
```

Comment: I tried using that code, it still took a good amount of time to run. I think I need to use the 'Union' method, along with adding the columns to be deleted to a single range, and then deleting that range... Trying to use that approach (see edited question) but code is still not working.

Comment: @sikorloa - using `Union` will not make any difference. In fact, it may make your code crash if you try to delete too many (especially non-contiguous) columns at once. Try turning calculations to manual so that excel does not recalc on every range area deletion (in my code). That will certainly speed up the code if it does not have to recalc after every removal.

Comment: Trying it now, using the code from [link](http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/calc-stop.htm) to turn off calculations. Still seems to be taking a few minutes.

Comment: It does seem to work a bit faster, but I also got the 'Union' method to work across all sheets and it gets it done in ~6 minutes for the whole workbook, vs a few hours using the other approach. I definitely appreciate the input though. Hopefully 'Union' method won't cause any problems, for the first runs it seems to be working OK

Comment: @sikorloa - I stand corrected. congrats on getting a better functioning code.